# loadコンストラクタ内容をbutton(別コンストラクタ)から呼び出すには？

Tags: c#

コンストラクタという呼び方であってるか分かりませんが、
どのようにすれば出来ますでしょうか？
よろしくお願いいたします。

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("hello world");
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //ここでForm1_Loadを呼び出したい
        }
    }

}
```

Windows 10 64bit /Visual Studio for Desktop 2015

Answer (score 1):

`Form1_Load`**メソッド**、あるいは`Form1.Load`**イベントハンドラー**を実行したい場合、以下のように記述します。

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form1_Load(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

これは`MessageBox.Show("hello world")`と文法的には同等の行為になります。上の例では`sender`として`this`、`e`に`EventArgs.Empty`と「APIとして正しい」値を指定していますが、`Form1_Load`メソッドで引数の値は参照されていないので、実引数値は`null`などでも構いません。

なおイベントハンドラーはコード中から直接実行するためのものではありませんので、より適切な方法としては別の共通メソッドを定義して`Form1_Load`と`button1_Click`から参照します。

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ShowHelloWorld();
}
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ShowHelloWorld();
}
private void ShowHelloWorld()
{
    MessageBox.Show("hello world");
}
```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
自分の中で色々と言葉がごっちゃになっているようで
分かりやすい説明をいただきとても助かります。
１つ気になるところがあったのですが、
        //共通メソッド
        private void ShowHelloWorld()
        {
            textBox1.Text = "aaa";
        }

        //これは共通メソッドではない？何といいますか？
        public static string ShowHelloWorld2()
  {
                    textBox1.Text = "aaa"; //エラー
      return "";
  }
コメント欄からの為見づらくて申し訳ございません。

Comment: @MAHOTO 「共通メソッド」とは技術的な用語ではありません。回答では単純に「共通部分を独立したメソッドに抽出したもの」という程度の意味で使用しております。